# How to bring the close(x) button of jQuery Tools Overlay to the left?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to use this jQuery plugin: [jQuery Tools: Overlay effect](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/styling.html)

It shows a light box in mac style with a black+white x-circle to close it. But it's on the upper right. Since my audience are Mac users, that would suck. How could I reposition that close-x icon to the left of the light box so that the usability doesn't get hurt?

Comment: LOL, it's a web-site. 99% of web-sites with pop-ups use an upper right X icon to close them. Your Mac users are used to it ...

Comment: I'm a hardcore mac user and I believe it sucks to close top right. But now you bring me to an cool idea: Just add two of them! One left, one right.

Comment: Now that you mentioned that, I figured out that the position of the close button can be adjusted easily based on the platform of the visitor. First the `userAgent` string is examined to determine the platform of the visitor (Win or Mac), and then CSS classes are set accordingly - those classes determine the position of the close button. Easy as pie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default style:

```
#custom div.close {
    right:-15px;
    top:-10px;
}
```

Change it to this:

```
#custom div.close {
    left:-15px;
    top:-10px;
}
```